# reponsive menu not working when i use variables

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

While this works fine:

```
$(".click").click(function () 
    $('#menu').slideToggle("veryslow");
});`
```

when i try and make variables it does not work

```
var menu = $("#menu");
var click = $(".click");
$(click).click(function () {
    (menu).slideToggle("slow", function () {});
});
```

i am trying to make a responsive nav.

Comment: You can use `click.click(function ()` and `menu.slideToggle...`

Comment: The code you've shown _does_ work (provided it is in a document ready handler and/or in a script element that appears after the elements in question): http://jsfiddle.net/yLg8ay9o/ Are there other errors in your code (check the browser console for errors, or just proof read it like you don't seem to have done with your question).

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
click.click(function () {
    menu.slideToggle("slow", function () {});
});
```

Explanation: It seams like your code did not work, because you has some invalid character inside.

Comment: Your suggestion is neater and more efficient than the OP's code, but given that the OP's code [should already work as is](http://jsfiddle.net/yLg8ay9o/) do you have an explanation why your suggestion would actually fix the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

You missed `$` sign before `menu`, see below code

```
var menu = $("#menu");
    var click = $(".click");

    $(click).click(function () {
        $(menu).slideToggle("slow", function () {});
    });
```

OR you can directly use the variable (without `$` sign)

```
   var menu = $("#menu");
    var click = $(".click");
   click.click(function () {
        menu.slideToggle("slow", function () {});
    });
```

Comment: _"You missed $ sign before menu, see below code"_ - the `$` isn't needed when `(menu)` is already a jQuery object. The original code works [as is](http://jsfiddle.net/yLg8ay9o/).